# Problems with group by and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am a newbie to the world of sql but struggling to get some of the basics to work.

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
Table name: Sample
    PROJECT      WORK ORDER      AMOUNT
     -----------------------------------------
     111             a             100
     222             b             200
     111             c             300
     444             d             400
     111             e             500
     666             f             600
```

I want it to end up looking like this:

```
Table name: Sample
    PROJECT      WORK ORDER      AMOUNT     PROJECT AMOUNT
     --------------------------------------------------------
     111             e             500           900
     111             c             300           900
     111             a             100           900
     666             f             600           600
     444             d             400           600
     222             b             200           200
```

Sorted by project with the greatest TOTAL amount

Group by does not work for me as it groups all projects into one, so I can't see the 3 work order lines for "Project 111"

```
PROJECT      WORK ORDER      AMOUNT
 -----------------------------------------
 111             a             900
 222             b             200
 444             d             400
 666             f             600
```

Order by does not work as I can't get it sort it out on the basis of the greatest project value

```
Table name: Sample
    PROJECT      WORK ORDER      AMOUNT
     -----------------------------------------
     666             f             600
     111             e             500
     444             d             400
     111             c             300
     222             b             200
     111             a             100
```

My alternative idea was if I could create another column "Project Amount" that calculates the projects total based on values in "Project" column and I can then easily sort it by Project Amount instead to achieve the desired format

```
Table name: Sample
    PROJECT      WORK ORDER      AMOUNT     PROJECT AMOUNT
     --------------------------------------------------------
     111             e             500           900
     111             c             300           900
     111             a             100           900
     666             f             600           600
     444             d             400           600
     222             b             200           200
```

But I am struggling how to get column "Project Amount" to calculate all the projects total value and present them on any rows that appear with the same project number.

Any advise?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I have tried like a thousand correct and in-correct code thought it would be easier for someone to tell me how they would do it. I think the code below has just sorted the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
,       sum(amount) over (partition by project) as ProjAmount
,       row_number() over 
from    YourTable
order by
        ProjAmount desc
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40d57/1/0)

---

To select only the top two projects with the highest amounts, you could use `dense_rank`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       dense_rank() over (order by ProjAmount desc) as dr
        from    (
                select  *
                ,       sum(amount) over (partition by project) as ProjAmount
                from    YourTable
                ) WithProjAmount
        ) WithDenseRank
where   dr < 3
order by
        ProjAmount desc
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40d57/3/0)

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, I spent almost 2 weeks trying all different types of codes pulling my hair out but I did it exactly how you would do it and it has worked fantastic. One final thing if you don't mind, how would I then select the "top 2". E.G. to only show the two greatest project amount, all the 111's and all the 666's?

Comment: That took quite a bit of tweaking of the tables from my side, the actual code I was working with had about 10 columns, joins to 7 tables and several more, but thanks a lot, I've got it to work thank you so much

Comment: how do I add a second order by after it's sorted it based on ProjAmount? On your first code I added amount after projamount desc and it worked. I added it on your second code, it reduced the result set to top 2 projects instead of top 2 projamount

Comment: The result set is always sorted by an `order by` at the end of the outer query.  Updated in answer.

Comment: your a star, sorry I looked at the order by in the dense rank code and thought it needed to go there as the result was already sorted in the right order of projamount so thought it needed to be input there, but your right, excellent :) do I need to do anything to vote for your help or is ticking the tick enough? Thanks again

Comment: You can vote for or against any answer with the up and down arrows next to the question.  You can accept one answer (the tick.)  Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

A version with plain SQL subquery

```
SELECT s.*,
       (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Sample WHERE Project = s.Project) ProjectAmount
  FROM Sample s
 ORDER BY ProjectAmount DESC
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bbde/2)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, the above code has got it to work, now just looking at how to select the top 2 project amounts. This community is great, first time using this site

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.project ,
        a.work  ,
        a.amount ,
        b.proj_amount
FROM    project A
        JOIN ( SELECT   SUM(amount) proj_amount ,
                        project
               FROM     project
               WHERE    project = project
               GROUP BY project
             ) b ON a.project = b.project
ORDER BY proj_amount DESC ,
        amount DESC
```